# How to plot a (grouped) bar chart from a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following data

```
      T1    SO    DR    AX    NO       Overig
SK1   20.2  21.7  27    22.4  22.6     25
PA    20.2  21.7  21.6  20.4  17.7     25.0
T4    30.8  30.0  24.3  28.6  32.3     0.0
XXS   7.7   10.0  10.8  8.2   9.7      25.0
MvM   20.2  16.7  13.5  18.4  14.5     25.0
ACH   1.0   0.0   2.7   2.0   3.2      0.0
```

With an specified index and columns.

I need a bar chart for just the columns T1, SO, and DR, with the index name on the x-axis, and the values of the index for the three columns on the y-axis. In this case the total of bars will be 6*3 = 18.
I have tried the following:

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar') 
tevr_asp[['T1','SO','DR']].T.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dataframe `plot` function to render specific columns in y-axis and with `use_index` you can render the index in x-axis.

```
df.plot(y=["T1", "SO", "DR"],use_index=True, kind="bar")
```

Comment: Hey, I get the error 
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: @sc_ams try `df=df.astype(float)` before plot.